# Kohana ORM relationships question

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have tables:

```
users {id, name}
projects {id, name}
roles {id, name}
projects_users {id, user_id, project_id, role_id}
```

I have models:

```
project { has many users through projects_users }
user { has many projects through projects_users }
```

**Question**:
How i get user roles for one project? Or maybe i have to reconstruct my tables?

Code:

```
$project = ORM::factory('project', $id);
$users = $project->users->find_all();
foreach ($users as $u) {
    $roles = $u-> .... How to get all roles for this user and for this project?
}
```

Comment: Although I am a newbie myself, this approach may apply to your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286539/kohana-3-orm-how-to-perform-query-with-2-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project_users table seems to be representing roles on projects, add another model which is tied to that table:

```
project_role { 
    has one user 
    has one role
    has one project
}
user {
    has many project_role
    ...
}
project {
    has many project_role
    ...
}
```

Then you might be able to do:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user')
    ->with('project_role')
    ->where('project_role.project_id', '=', $id)
    ->with('project_role:role')->findall();
```

If that doesn't work, one of the following should work, but may be a different form of traversal to what you're after.

```
$project = ORM::factory('project', $id);
$roles = $project->project_role->with('user')->with('role')->findall();
```

Or

```
$roles = ORM::factory('project_role')
    ->where('project_id', '=', $id)
    ->with('user')->with('role')->findall();
```