# Kohana 3 ORM: Multiple joins

Tags: orm, kohana

I have Kohana ORM/Mysql query problem. I hope you can help.

To start of, here's the diagram of tables:

[image: Diagram]

Here's my ORM definitions:

MEMBERS has many TOPICS through MEMBERS_TOPICS
ARTICLES has many TOPICS though ARTICLES_TOPICS
TOPICS has many MEMBERS though MEMBERS_TOPICS
TOPICS has many ARTICLES though ARTICLES_TOPICS

Think of it as a mailing list where you have members that has chosen topics of articles in which topics are also assigned to particular topics.

I couldn't figure out how to make a single query so I can return joined results and send an email to individual members with articles they only chose through the topics they've chosen.

I hope to receive wisdom with mysql/kohana ninjas around. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`with()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#with) method in ORM that will join your tables, provided you have relations setup correctly in your models. Below a small example:

*Model:*

```
public function find_all_orders()
{
   return $this->with('customer')->with('product')->find_all();
}
```

*View:*

```
foreach ($orders as $order)
{
   echo $order->product->name . ' ' . $order->customer->name;
}
```

The relations are:

- order belongs to product, product has many orders
- order belongs to customer, customer has many orders

Answer (score 0):

ORM does have a join() method: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#join

There's possibly a more elegant KO3 way to do what you want, but I'm not entirely familiar with KO3 ORM, perhaps someone else can suggest a better way.

[edit]
Some further reading:

- [Kohana 3 ORM: How to perform query with 2 many to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286539/kohana-3-orm-how-to-perform-query-with-2-many-to-many-relationships)